# MVN archetype generate a sub project structure (grunt and package.json)

Tags: maven, aem

I'm adding to the  adobe aem archetype https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype . I'm trying to have the archetype create a directory directory call ui.resources with a Gruntfile and package.json in it. I place those files in a ui.resources directory in src/main/archetype. When I run mvn archetype:generate and point to it, there's a gruntfile placed under ui.resource/{packageName} . What am I missing in the archetype-metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, there's a package option in the fillets